# How do I find which pins my TFT display is using?

Tags: gpio, display, touchscreen, spi, pitft

I have a [TFT Touch Screen Display from Tontec](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NANNJLQ) that I'm using for a project. According to the product description the display only uses 8 pins. However, the connector cable takes up 26 pins worth of space and I would like to use the other pins as well.

I was going to manually connect the necessary cables, however I haven't been able to figure out which pins to use. I was hoping [this pinout](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pitft_plus_35) would match, but it didn't work.

I am using the fbturbo driver, any ideas on how I can find out exactly which pins the display needs?

Comment: looks more like 26 pins - look at the traces on the pin header - you should see what is and isn't connected

Comment: @JaromandaX, you're right! I think I mistyped, fixed the question to be 26. Thanks for the suggestion on looking at the traces on the pin header! So far I got the screen to turn on, but it's only white. However, that's better than what I tried before. :)